# Setting a footer in a ListView

Tags: android, xml, listview, footer

I need to add a button at the end of my application, without the items covering the button. With my current code the button is being covered by the items in the ListView. I wanna be able to scroll through the ListView and see all the items, without the button being covered with them. I need button with id "bSave" below the Listview. My XML code:

Button

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/bottom_control_bar"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

    <Button android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Spara total tid"
        android:id="@+id/bSave" android:textStyle="bold"
        android:visibility="invisible"></Button>
</LinearLayout>
```

ListView

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/bottom_control_bar"></ListView>
    <TextView android:id="@android:id/empty"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Do you want the buttons to be inside the list at the end or always visible at the bottom of the screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want the button to always be visible, or to only be visible once you read the end of the list? If the former, then you use something like a `relativelayout` with a footer button set to `alignparentbottom` and `below` the `listview`. If the latter, then call `listview.addFooterView`, passing in whatever view you'd like.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a ScrollView http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html

```
<LinearLayout>
<ScrollView>
</ScrollView>

<Button>
</Button>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I need a listview to display my items